# Python - Selenium test gets stuck on trying to accept an alert

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to python-selenium and was implementing an automation script which checks for a specific mail and sends it to intended client from outlook office mail. On clicking on forward mail button , a new window opens along with an alert which has options to select "OK" or "Cancel".I am able to switch to window using window_handles and also switch to the corresponding alert, But accepting the alert gets stalled and nothing happens until i manually go and press the ok button.

```
window_handle_names = self.driver.window_handles
time.sleep(10)
self.driver.switch_to_window(window_handle_names[1])
time.sleep(10)
alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

I am using a dom based model where i have subclassed webdriver and webelements. I could see that execution occurs till switch_to_alert(), but as soon as accept is encountered everything stalls
Note:execution is done in chrome, i haven't tested the same in Firefox

Comment: This cmd is deprecated.

Comment: @Tnerual, but it still can be used

Comment: @Andersson For sure. But it may be removed from a future release. And this may already be so. See [PEP4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/) for details. I guess that as new selenium user, the OP downloaded and uses the last version. Do you ? I admit I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`switch_to_alert` is deprecated](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_alert). Which means that a better alternative exists. And this alternative is

```
alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
```

### update

Alternatively -- as you suggested -- you can try to disable the alert by injecting the following js redefinition

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
```

Comment: I tried switch_to.alert.accept() also but with no luck. Still the test hangs when the alert box is encountered .
I think this problem might be with the chrome driver. saw an open issue : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1467

Is there any other way i can remove the javascript alert ? by injecting some javascript into the browser ??

Comment: I don't know why but all of a sudden self.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()  started working and i was able to accept the alert. Seemed like i had changed some execution flow when switch_to_alert was not working which meant the first option you provided didn't work. However i recorded the alert part from scratch today and your solution worked perfectly. Thank you